# I can't install RVM and Ruby on Vagrant (box "hashicorp/precise64")

Tags: ruby, vagrant, rvm

everyone! I've followed the instructions from https://rvm.io/integration/vagrant

So in Vargantfile I have:

```
config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision/install-rvm.sh", args: "stable", privileged: false
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision/install-ruby.sh", args: "1.9.3", privileged: false
config.vm.provision :shell, path: "provision/install-ruby.sh", args: "2.0.0 rails haml", privileged: false
```

in install-rvm.sh:

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s $1
```

in install-ruby.sh:

```
source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm || source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh 
rvm use --default --install $1
shift
if (( $# ))
then gem install $@
fi
rvm cleanup all
```

but after `vagrant up` it says:

```
==> default: gpg: requesting key D39DC0E3 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
==> default: gpg: key D39DC0E3: "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>" not changed
==> default: gpg: Total number processed: 1
==> default: gpg:              unchanged: 1
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 4: curl: command not found
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
default: Running: /tmp/vagrant-shell20170120-19193-117iyxj.sh
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 3: /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 3: /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh: No such file or directory
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 5: rvm: command not found
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 13: rvm: command not found
```

But if I run the same provision with rvm and ruby on "ubuntu/trusty64"
everything works just fine

Comment: can you ssh in and see if curl is installed?

Comment: You need to install curl before attempting to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RVM depends on `curl` - add extra line to install curl like:

```
apt-get install curl
```

before any calls to rvm scripts